# I can't reach phpmyadmin

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin, lighttpd

I have installed php,apache and mysql. After phpmyadmin using this code:

> sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

I can see any problem when i'm installing phpmyadmin. But I can't reach.

[image]

I fellow [this](http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/) resource, when i installing package.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the guide that you linked, but you need to restart `apache2` after installing `phpmyadmin`. Do `sudo service apache2 restart`. If it doesn't work after that, you might need to place an explicit `Alias` direction in your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem. I selected apache. Before this is not selected.
For solve:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin

Comment: Yusuf: this is likely to really help someone out in the future. Could you take a minute to provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message today but when I checked, I found out that phpmyadmin was saved to `/usr/share`. So I ran:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`
And http://localhost/phpmyadmin worked.